# GUI музыкального стана в Android/IOS

Tags: android, ios, gui

Как правильно спроектировать GUI например на Android нотного стана из пяти линеечек (+есть ведь и добавочные короткие линии)? Например, есть пять линий. Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии КАК на саму линию, так и между линиями (я уж не говорю про добавочные) происходило обращение к конкретной ноте. Сделать ли это отдельными элементами, например, прямоугольник с пересекающей его линией как одна нота, прямоугольник пустой как другая. Или же вообще взять просто изображение и по dip-ам пропорционально высчитывать куда же попал пользователь: на линию или между линиями? Как лучше, помогите продумать, пожалуйста.

Comment: писать свой View

Comment: Каждую строку как отдельный слой или элемент, например чёрная строка один элемент, белая другой со своим идентификатором, и дальше уже работать с ними.Т.е. У вас будет набор белых и чёрных прямоугольников вертикальных со своими идентификаторами.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете свой кастомный View. В нем перегружаете onDraw, в котором рисуете и стан, и ноты, и все прочие символы которые могут вам пригодится. Придется научится определять во что именно попал своим тыком пользователь, выделять выбранные элементы, скролить стан вправо/влево и еще кучу всего. Не забыть учесть что ваша вьюшка может меняться в размерах и пересоздаваться вместе с активити, и еще много чего.

Вариант с использованием кучи вьюшек даже не рассматривайте. Скролинг лайаута с парой сотен элементов на смартфонах среднего и малого бюджетного диапазона вызовет у юзера желание разбить девайс об стену. Значительно эффективнее все эти элементы отрисовывать самому внутри одной view. Родных возможностей Canvas-а должно хватить с лихвой.

Когда будете сохранять набранные данные не забудьте про midi. Я бы вообще для начала научился читать миди-файлы и отображать дорожки из них. Они вам помогут понять что еще надо реализовывать